# Setting Range Using xlToLeft Fails After 256'th Column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-2003

I have been looping through and copying data from some raw data files using VBA. For each iteration I have been using the following code to define the destination range:

```
Set destinationRange = WorksheetRange.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
```

This works fine up until the 256'th column. After this, instead of setting the destination range as the next empty cell in row 2 it goes back to cell (2,2) as if the starting reference cell (.Cells(2, Columns.Count)) is within the occupied range and the .End method is going back to the beginning of the occupied range. But this shouldn't be the case, even during runtime I have verified that Columns.Count is equal to 16384 as it should be. So why is it that the code is seemingly using cell (2,256) as the result of .Cells(2, Columns.Count)? I have also tried adding a value into a cell many columns past 256 to try and remove any sort of behavior involving placeholder values for Columns.Count but this did not work either.

Appreciate any insight into this. It is also worth noting that no runtime errors are tripped, the copied data simply begins to overwrite in column 2 after reaching column 256.

Comment: Do you mean that if you type something into cell 2,500 `destinationRange` is still cell 2,256? Don't see how that can be.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Is there actually data in row 2 in any column past B?

Comment: Is there always data in row 2 of the raw data files?

Comment: So I just ran a quick experiment along the lines of what @SJR said, where I have placed a value in cell (2, 200) and cell (2,500). When looping through a folder with 10 data files and copying one column from each file I end up with data in columns 201-210 when the expected result would be data in columns 501-510. If I repeat this experiment with values in cell (2,200) and cell (2, 250) I end up with the data from files 2-6 in columns 252-256 and then the data from file 10 in column 251, as if the data from file 1 was overwritten by data from file 7, then 8, ..., 10.

Comment: @BigBen There was data in every column up to 256 (in the initial situation, in an experiment I have also tried it with more sparse values as described in my previous comment)

Comment: Are you using xl2003 files - seem to recall the column limit was 256, perhaps this is an issue.

Comment: @SJR okay now we might be getting  somewhere, the worksheet that the code is running from is the current version of Excel but the source data files are xl2003.

Comment: `WorksheetRange.Cells(2, WorksheetRange.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)`

Comment: So this is a rare case when omitting a sheet from `columns.count` does put a spanner in the works. Follow BigBen's advice and should be ok.

Comment: @BigBen yes WorksheetRange is a worksheet object I just changed its name in the post for privacy, and this is all within a "With (workbook object)" statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "The worksheet that the code is running from is the current version of Excel but the source data files are xl2003".

Probably you're getting bitten by an implicit `ActiveSheet`:

```
WorksheetRange.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
```

Should be

```
WorksheetRange.Cells(2, WorksheetRange.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
```

Since the `ActiveSheet` (xl2003) only has 256 columns, `End(xlToLeft)` returns to column 1 after the 256th column.